# Find the largest ASCII character in a string recursively - java

Tags: java, string, recursion

I am trying to write a method which returns the largest character in a string according to ASCII (a character is greater if it comes later in the ASCII table). This is what I have so far,

```
public char maxChar (String s) {
    char[] characters = s.toCharArray();
    char character = characters[0];
    return maxCharHelper(characters, character, 0);
}

private static char maxCharHelper(char[] characters, char character, int index) {
    if (index >= characters.length - 1) {
        return character;
    }
    if (characters[index] > character) {
        character++;
    }
    return maxCharHelper(characters, character, ++index);
}
```

I receive three issues which are: 
1) when string `"helloWORLD"` is used it returns 107(k) instead of 111(o)
2) when string `"helloworld"` is used it returns 110(n) instead of 119(w)
lastly, 3) when string `"abbxL ? 12 x5y @"` is used it returns 101(e) instead of 121(y)
Not sure why this happens, is there anything wrong with my code? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `character++;` with `character = characters[index]` and it will work!

and replace `index >= characters.length - 1` with `index > characters.length - 1`, else the last character wont be checked.

Comment: Wouldn't `index >= characters.length` be better? Why do the subtraction at all?